# IncompatibleClassChangeError on running Consumer

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am trying to use reactor-kafka in my jar. Below is pom.xml.

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactive-kakfa</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.30-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.projectreactor.kafka/reactor-kafka -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Below is the kafka consumer code written

```
    public Mono SampleConsumer(String bootstrapServers) {
        System.out.printf("Received message in bean");
        Map<String, Object> consumerProps = new HashMap();
        consumerProps.put("bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers);
        consumerProps.put("group.id", "sample-group");
        consumerProps.put("key.deserializer", IntegerDeserializer.class);
        consumerProps.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        ReceiverOptions<Object, Object> receiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.<Object, Object>create(consumerProps)
                .subscription(Collections.singleton(TOPIC));
        Flux<ReceiverRecord<Object, Object>> inboundFlux =
                KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions)
                        .receive();
        inboundFlux.subscribe(r -> {
            System.out.printf("Received message: %s\n", r);
            r.receiverOffset().acknowledge();
        });

        return Mono.just("some msg");
    }
```

I am facing this issue while creating the ReceiverOptions Object

`java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class reactor.kafka.receiver.ReceiverOptions, but interface was expected`

I am using kafka-2.3.1 and  have tried clean build also invalidated cache and restarted intellij. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You do not need to provide a version for the `reactor-kafka` dependency in your build configuration, as Spring Boot [manages](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-dependency-management) that for you.